# Output is not displayed properly while print the string value "The" is not aligning properly

Tags: java, string

```
package com.tp.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DuplicateString {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String res = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("============Input=============");

        String str = br.readLine();

        while (str.length() > 0) {
            int c = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(j))
                    c = c + 1;
            }

            res = "The" + res + str.charAt(0) + " repeated for " + c + " times " + "\n";
            String k[] = str.split(str.charAt(0) + "");
            str = new String("");

            for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
                str = str + k[i];
        }

        System.out.print(res);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
sfkljsdkjds
TheTheTheTheTheThes repeated for 3 times 
f repeated for 1 times 
k repeated for 2 times 
l repeated for 1 times 
j repeated for 2 times 
d repeated for 2 times
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the string value “The” is not aligning properly*? what are you expecting to get?

Comment: `res = "The" + res + ...` don't you mean `res = res + "The" + ...`? It's odd that you parse the previous `res` in the middle of your string.

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to let community help you

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori the OP removed the question portion of this. They wanted to know why they were getting the above output `TheTheTheTheTheThes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep on appending `res` each time within the string and there is no space after `the`. Try using `StringBuilder` to build up the final string you need

for Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.println("============Input=============");

  String str = br.readLine();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  while (str.length() > 0) {
    int c = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
      if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(j))
        c += 1;
    }

    sb.append(String.format("The %s repeated for %d times\n", str.charAt(0),  c));
    str = str.replace(str.subSequence(0, 1), "");
  }

  System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```

Yo can see that we created a StringBuilder class and keep on appending to it. Using `String.Format` we can build up the string in a readable fashion as well. Then we print the final results.

```
============Input=============
sfkljsdkjds
The s repeated for 3 times
The f repeated for 1 times
The k repeated for 2 times
The l repeated for 1 times
The j repeated for 2 times
The d repeated for 2 times
```

Also, since we are grabbing the first letter of the string each time we can also replace those occurrences with an empty value as shown above which simplifies the loop.